# Something its slowing this Wordpress. Server origin? o files origin?

Tags: wordpress, performance

I have analyzed my new website with GTmetrix ([see report](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.brunchear.com/DtA1tGbN)) and i have a 95% score in Google pagespeed. But the time of loading at the start of loading its very slow. (more than 10 seconds)
The technical support of my hosting says that maybe a query its slowing all. But i cant find the origin.
Can you help me?

I have try P3 plugin and
Waterfall Analysis say this in header response:

```
<html lang="es-ES" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">

<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">

<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">

<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">

<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

<title>

    Inicio - Brunchear.comBrunchear.com | Tu guia de brunch y desayunos</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.brunchear... [truncated to save space (240874 more bytes)]
```

Thanks 
The website its [www.brunchear.com](http://www.brunchear.com)

Comment: Not sure why you've posted an entire html page's source in your question... but I can't see it all on my phone and can't figure out what you're trying to show. Are you able to show only the relevant information?

Comment: The code its a header response, sorry. I have edit it. I also add the gtmetrix report. Thank for your attention

Comment: Ok I still can't figure out what it is and why it's there, but did P3 Profiler say any plugins in particular are causing long load times? Whether it did or not, if you disable all of your plugins does it help? You can then enable them one by one to track down which one is causing the issue. Alternatively it might be your theme... try changing that and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: Also note GT Metrix' report is for front-end issues only, ie after the server has delivered the page. You can still get a great reading from GT Metrix but have issues on the backend. Another route to try could be a caching plugin, eg W3 Total Cache

Comment: The backend works fine. Its something in the frontend. P3 profiler show normal parameters

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the biggest problem is that you call

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css
```

that returns a 400 Error and it slow down the page because the browser try to load that content

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked your gtmetrix results, and well yes it's severely slow.

Minimum things to do:

1. get a better hosting
2. install cache plugins, w3 total cache e.g.
3. use cdn, amazon works wonders! also use photon for images

If you're not confident in these steps and also wants code modifications to optimize your site speed, there are services like: http://pagespeedpro.com/ that can help you improve your speed easily.